# Cannot resolve module react-paypal-button-v3

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I see the following error when running my react app. I already installed the package using npm install --save.

I'm running react version 17.02.

Can someone please help?

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-paypal-button-v3'
```

My package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "color-thief-react": "^2.0.10",
    "export-from-json": "^1.1.4",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "query-string": "^6.8.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.0",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.1.0",
    "react-date-range": "^1.1.3",
    "react-lazyload": "^2.6.2",
    "react-meta-tags": "^0.7.4",
    "react-paypal-button-v3": "^3.0.2",
}
```

Comment: How can we reproduce the error?